# How to apply fade animation or any other animation from display none to display block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have provided the javascript code that I have used to apply to hide and appear the read more text on clicking the button and it is working very fine but now the client wants that the text should appear and hide with any animation. I don't know what should I apply fade or slide or something else to show it to the client. I don't know how to do that.

```js
    function ReadmoreFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more-text");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("readMoreBtn");
    
      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
```

```css
 #more-text{
    display: none;
    transition: 2s;
 }
 #readMoreBtn{
  background: #ff963b;
  color: #fff;
  border:1px solid #ff963b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="category-description std">
        <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></h2>
    
        <p style="text-align:=justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur efficitur sodales erat luctus blandit. Vestibulum rutrum tellus fermentum massa pharetra maximus. Morbi sit amet metus vel massa tempus iaculis. Ut sit amet ligula dolor. Nam a sem at est sagittis volutpat. Vestibulum dapibus et orci eu placerat. Suspendisse placerat quis elit sed fringilla. Praesent finibus vestibulum augue in auctor. Etiam interdum dolor mi, ut facilisis magna malesuada ut. Fusce sed eros nibh.</p><span id="dots"></span>
    <span id="more-text">
        <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>**Get best quality art and craft supplies within your budget**</strong></h2>
    
        <p style="text-align:=justify;">Integer hendrerit suscipit quam ultrices tristique. Integer vel tortor vel risus ultrices tempus tempor a mauris. Etiam venenatis, elit non aliquam sollicitudin, diam tellus dictum lacus, ac scelerisque metus purus nec quam. Donec elementum vitae erat sed condimentum. Aliquam at lorem mollis, porttitor dui at, finibus magna. Aliquam id efficitur lectus, eu ultricies nibh. Nam et posuere mauris, eget hendrerit nisi. Curabitur non tortor enim.</p>
        
        <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </strong></h2>
    
        <p style="text-align:=justify;">Integer hendrerit suscipit quam ultrices tristique. Integer vel tortor vel risus ultrices tempus tempor a mauris. Etiam venenatis, elit non aliquam sollicitudin, diam tellus dictum lacus, ac scelerisque metus purus nec quam. Donec elementum vitae erat sed condimentum. Aliquam at lorem mollis, porttitor dui at, finibus magna. Aliquam id efficitur lectus, eu ultricies nibh. Nam et posuere mauris, eget hendrerit nisi. Curabitur non tortor enim.</p></span>
    </div>
    <center><button onclick="ReadmoreFunction()" id="readMoreBtn">Read more</button></center>
```

Comment: For example you can use jQuery Effects, like slide or fade...

Comment: lol i am asking how?? and i don't want to use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Ok here I made some changes to your code to use font-size instead of display, to apply transition effect

```js
function ReadmoreFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more-text");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("readMoreBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.fontSize = "0";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.fontSize = "initial";
  }
}
```

```css
#more-text{
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 1s font-size;
}
#readMoreBtn {
  background: #ff963b;
  color: #fff;
  border:1px solid #ff963b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-description std">
  <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></h2>
  
  <p style="text-align:=justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur efficitur sodales erat luctus blandit. Vestibulum rutrum tellus fermentum massa pharetra maximus. Morbi sit amet metus vel massa tempus iaculis. Ut sit amet ligula dolor. Nam a sem at est sagittis volutpat. Vestibulum dapibus et orci eu placerat. Suspendisse placerat quis elit sed fringilla. Praesent finibus vestibulum augue in auctor. Etiam interdum dolor mi, ut facilisis magna malesuada ut. Fusce sed eros nibh.</p><span id="dots"></span>
  <span id="more-text">
    <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>**Get best quality art and craft supplies within your budget**</strong></h2>
    
    <p style="text-align:=justify;">Integer hendrerit suscipit quam ultrices tristique. Integer vel tortor vel risus ultrices tempus tempor a mauris. Etiam venenatis, elit non aliquam sollicitudin, diam tellus dictum lacus, ac scelerisque metus purus nec quam. Donec elementum vitae erat sed condimentum. Aliquam at lorem mollis, porttitor dui at, finibus magna. Aliquam id efficitur lectus, eu ultricies nibh. Nam et posuere mauris, eget hendrerit nisi. Curabitur non tortor enim.</p>
        
    <h2 style="text-align:=justify;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </strong></h2>
    
    <p style="text-align:=justify;">Integer hendrerit suscipit quam ultrices tristique. Integer vel tortor vel risus ultrices tempus tempor a mauris. Etiam venenatis, elit non aliquam sollicitudin, diam tellus dictum lacus, ac scelerisque metus purus nec quam. Donec elementum vitae erat sed condimentum. Aliquam at lorem mollis, porttitor dui at, finibus magna. Aliquam id efficitur lectus, eu ultricies nibh. Nam et posuere mauris, eget hendrerit nisi. Curabitur non tortor enim.</p>
  </span>

  <center><button onclick="ReadmoreFunction()" id="readMoreBtn">Read more</button></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we use opacity instead of fontsize to give it fade effect?